# Custom Flask Decorator Causing UnboundLocalError

Tags: python-2.7, flask

I'm mocking up a service for a development environment, and have written a custom view decorator to check for an authorization token. When writing the custom decorator I followed Flasks documentation for a similar decorator [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/viewdecorators/#login-required-decorator). The issue I'm having is that I now get an UnboundLocalError.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jgoodell/virtualenvs/mock-zoom-api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/jgoodell/virtualenvs/mock-zoom-api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Users/jgoodell/virtualenvs/mock-zoom-api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/jgoodell/virtualenvs/mock-zoom-api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/jgoodell/virtualenvs/mock-zoom-api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/jgoodell/virtualenvs/mock-zoom-api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/jgoodell/virtualenvs/mock-zoom-api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/jgoodell/virtualenvs/mock-zoom-api/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/jgoodell/code/python/mock-zoom-api/app.py", line 28, in decorated_function
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jgoodell/code/python/mock-zoom-api/app.py", line 35, in users
    if request.method == 'GET':
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'request' referenced before assignment
```

Here is the source code from which the error arrises.

```
from functools import wraps
import logging
import json

from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import make_response

from mock_zoom_api.auth import check_token
from mock_zoom_api.auth import InvalidTokenError


app = Flask(__name__)

logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


def require_token(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        logger.debug('%s', request.headers)
        try:
            token = request.headers['Authorization']
        except KeyError, InvalidTokenError:
            return make_response('Unauthorized', 401)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function


@app.route('/v2/users', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@require_token
def users():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        json_dict = {
            "page_count": "integer",
            "page_number": "integer",
            "page_size": "integer",
            "total_records": "integer",
            "users": [
                {
                    "id": "string",
                    "first_name": "string",
                    "last_name": "string",
                    "email": "string",
                    "type": "integer",
                    "pmi": "string",
                    "timezone": "string",
                    "dept": "string",
                    "created_at": "string [date-time]",
                    "last_login_time": "string [date-time]",
                    "last_client_version": "string"
                    }
                ]
            }
        response = make_response(json.dumps(json_dict), 200)
        response.headers['Content Type'] = 'application/json'
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        response = make_response('Success', 201)
        response.headers['Content Type'] = 'text/plain'
    else:
        request = make_response('Method Not Allowed', 405)
        response.headers['Content Type'] = 'text/plain'
    return response
```

The stack trace is clear, from the decorator it is expected that 'request' be passed to the function that is decorated, and If I pass 'request' explicitly the error goes away. Here is the refactored code that does work.

```
from functools import wraps
import logging
import json

from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import make_response

from mock_zoom_api.auth import check_token
from mock_zoom_api.auth import InvalidTokenError


app = Flask(__name__)

logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


def require_token(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        logger.debug('%s', request.headers)
        try:
            token = request.headers['Authorization']
        except KeyError, InvalidTokenError:
            return make_response('Unauthorized', 401)
        return f(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function


@app.route('/v2/users', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@require_token
def users(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        json_dict = {
            "page_count": "integer",
            "page_number": "integer",
            "page_size": "integer",
            "total_records": "integer",
            "users": [
                {
                    "id": "string",
                    "first_name": "string",
                    "last_name": "string",
                    "email": "string",
                    "type": "integer",
                    "pmi": "string",
                    "timezone": "string",
                    "dept": "string",
                    "created_at": "string [date-time]",
                    "last_login_time": "string [date-time]",
                    "last_client_version": "string"
                    }
                ]
            }
        response = make_response(json.dumps(json_dict), 200)
        response.headers['Content Type'] = 'application/json'
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        response = make_response('Success', 201)
        response.headers['Content Type'] = 'text/plain'
    else:
        request = make_response('Method Not Allowed', 405)
        response.headers['Content Type'] = 'text/plain'
    return response
```

What smells funny is the following. Why do I have to pass 'request' from within the decorator to the wrapped function, but I do not have to pass 'json'? Both are imported in the module and referenced inside my view. But only 'request' is raising the UnboundLocalError, not 'json'.

Here is the version information for my environment.

```
(mock-zoom-api)[0]mock-zoom-api$ pip freeze
click==6.7
Flask==0.12.2
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
MarkupSafe==1.0
Werkzeug==0.14.1
(mock-zoom-api)[0]mock-zoom-api$ python --version
Python 2.7.10
```

Answer (score 0):

`request` comes automatically with the routing.  Change:

```
def users(request):
```

to

```
def users():
```

Comment: What is being suggested is how I would expect "request" to be accessible, but does not accessible and causes the UnboundLocalError. See and read the post for more details.

Comment: ?? Change `def users(request):` to `def users():` and tell us the error you are getting.  You don't pass `request` in that menner.